# Select random data based on criteria

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

Suppose I have a table with 4 fields

```
table (id, alpha, beta, delta, gamma)
```

Then I want to select rows based on the following criteria

1. all 4 fields (`alpha`, `beta`, `delta`, `gamma`) are not null
2. for each combination of the fields (`alpha`, `beta`, `delta`, `gamma`), it has at least 7 rows

   ```
   SELECT alpha, beta, delta, gamma
   FROM table
   GROUP BY alpha, beta, delta, gamma
   HAVING COUNT(*) >= 7
   ```
3. Randomly select 7 to 10 rows from each group

So I can probably do this with a series of (or a big complex) SQL queries, but is this possible if I want to use dask collections or pandas dataframe?

My current attempt is through `dask.bag`, and obviously it is not so efficient

```
bag = (db.read_text('/path/to/the/jsonlines')
       .map(ujson.loads)
       .filter(lambda x: x['alpha'] and x['beta'] and x['delta'] and x['gamma'])
       .groupby(lambda x: (x['alpha'], x['beta'], x['delta'], x['gamma']))
       .filter(lambda x: len(x[1]) > 7))
```

EDIT: The database is expected to grow over time constantly. The collection of jsonlines files is the current snapshot of the data I need to include for the task (i.e. I don't want the newly added data).

is there a better way?